# Menus - Open items in new tab/window?

Tags: menus

I have 3.1.2 running with the Boldy theme.

[Site link.](http://www.dekho.com.au/)

I have a menu that has a number of external links listed in the items.
By default, these items do NOT load in a new tab/window.

There is no option in the Admin --> Appearance --> Menus, to tick a box to say open in new window.

How do I get them to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your WordPress admin panel, go to `Appearance > Menus`. Select `Screen Options` in the top right corner. Enable the property `Link Target`. Now you can set your link target element in your external link.

[image: Screen Options]

[image: Enable Link Target]

[image: Set Link Target on link]